# SQL Server 2005 transactional replication performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, replication, transactional-replication

Does anybody know how transactional replication have impact to performance of publisher database? I want to use a subscriber as a base for generate on-line reports and statistics (use transactional replication for copy data), but I don't know how it could reduce performance of source database (or not).

The source server: SQL 2005 Standard, VMWare, 4 CPU (16 cores), 16 GB RAM

The destination server: SQL 2005 Standard, VMWare, 1 CPU (4 cores), 8 GB RAM

Answer (score 1):

Well... yes and no.  Transactional replication is asynchronous, so it's not as though your performance will slow down merely because there's a publication. However, depending on how much extra horsepower you have to spare on the server right now, the log reader might put you over the top. Also note that the semantics of when a log record can be cleared from the transaction log change with transactional replication, so be careful there.